# How do I export all grades for all courses in Moodle?

Tags: php, mysql, database, moodle

I'm currently trying to export grades for Students in the Moodle 3.1 platform. At current there is a way to export grades for one course but no way of exporting all grades in all courses.
I've tried adding the Report Configuration plugin and following the advice in this thread https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=129901
However whenever I enter the code in the first block, it says [[nosemicolon]] and does not save. 
I was hoping someone could help me with this method or recommend a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Since it was almost year ago it probably isn't an issue any more. But in case somebody ended up here via google search: 
`Nosemicolon` error indicates that you have semicolon somewhere in your query. This plugin requires sql statements to be in a specific format.

Two things that  I remember that it's looking for are:

- No semicolon at the end of query
- Table names without `mdl_` prefix.